# Add a row if there are less than 5, otherwise replace the lowest number in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm pretty stuck on a Mysql query.
I have a table with three columns;

```
 user_id | person_id | score.
```

The table is going to be used to store top 5 highscores for each person.

I need at query that checks if there is less than five rows for a specific person.
Is there is less, insert new row. But if there is five rows I have to replace the lowest score with the new one.

It is for a webservice written in PHP and the data about the new score is posted to the method as params.

Been stuck for some hours now — is it even possible to make this happen in one query ?

Comment: and why more than one query is wrong?

Comment: also what is `user_id` vs. `person_id`?

Comment: I'd personally add all scores and when I need it, use a `LIMIT 0,5`... That way, you could have all the users check back on all of their attempts.

Comment: Never said more than one query is wrong. user_id is the player and person_id is the character being played.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use stored procedure in mysql. I dont know the names of the tables but if you look closer you will understand how it works.

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS test $$
CREATE PROCEDURE test( IN testparam VARCHAR(22) )
BEGIN
 DECLARE count INT(11);
 SET count = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM persons );
 IF count < 5 THEN
  insert into table_needed_for_insert values(testparam);
 ELSE
  update table_needed_for_insert where score=(select min(score) from table_needed_for_insert);
 END IF;

 select * from table_needed_for_insert
END $$
DELIMITER;
```

And how to execute this thing CALL test(1); 1 is the parameter, you can create as many as you need.
And from php you can call directly as like

```
$result = mysql_query("call test(".$param.")");
```

And here you can check a tutorial on mysql stored procedures:
http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-stored-procedure-tutorial.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible if you have a unique key which identifies the lowest score. Then you could use the 
INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY construct. But you would have to install a trigger which keeps explicit track of the lowest score.

Answer (score 0):

I would propose this scenario (I have not tried it, it is just an idea):

as I understand, you only need 5 ids. you can run a subqueries like these

```
SELECT MAX(id) AS last_id FROM table

SELECT MIN(score), id AS lowest_id FROM table
```

then

```
insert or replace into table (id, ...) values ( MIN(last_id+1, lowest_id),  ... )
```

there are possible mistakes and also only one subquery is possible, but I hope you get the main idea

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way imo is to insert data,

```
INSERT INTO top_scores (user_id, person_id, score_id) VALUES (1,2,3)
```

then delete inappropriate rows

```
DELETE top_scores FROM top_scores
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT * FROM top_scores WHERE person_id = 2 ORDER BY score ASC LIMIT 5, 1000000) AS inappropriate_rows 
USING (user_id, person_id, score)
```